# Measure memory usage of a short-lived process

Tags: c, memory, profiling

I am writing a small VM (link for those interested: http://github.com/tekknolagi/carp) and am curious as to how much memory a it uses.

I checked out Valgrind's Massif, but the output seems either wrong or limited (possibly because I am on OS X).

I would like to run something like: `memprofile -- ./carp.out -f examples/carp/reg.carp` and have it print out how much memory it uses. Is this possible? Willing to profile on Linux as well (on a VPS).

The reason I can't use something like `top` is: a) it's going to be in the kilobytes of memory usage (I think) and b) the program exits in less than a second.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred non-invasive method is running the program under `gdb` and putting a breakpoint in `exit`, then inspecting `/proc/$pid/smaps` (if on Linux; otherwise use the equivalent on your system) once the breakpoint is hit. Using `top` also works but tends to give you less information.

Comment: I like this - but is there no utility to monitor it in real time (aside from top)?